# ValueError:[number] is not in the list, even though it is and the code i believe is correct

Tags: list, input, indexing, numbers

When i execute this testing code below, i get the error below it:

```
my_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

my_input = input("Pick a number from 1 to 10?")
number_index = my_numbers.index(my_input)
print(number_index)
```

ERROR-----

> number_index = my_numbers.index(my_input) ValueError: '1' is not in
>   list

Answer (score 0):

is this python? if so, look like is python 3, then the error is simple: `input` give you a string, and you have a list of integers and no integer is going to be equal to a string, ever, so when you pass `my_input`, a string, to `index` it search in the list `my_numbers` for a match but all the things inside it are integer so it fail and give the error. The solution is simple transform the input to a integer like this:

```
my_input = int( input("Pick a number from 1 to 10?") )
```

the same apply to other languages but the fine details may vary...